# How do I specify a JPA ManyToOne relationship based on the id being another property

Tags: jpa, annotations, many-to-one

If I have an entity, say, ExchangeRate, with an id of currencyCode

```
@Entity
public class ExchangeRate {
    @Id
    private String currencyCode;
    private double rate;
}
```

and I have, say, a Price object that has a currencyCode property

```
@Entity
public class Price {
    @Id
    private String priceId;

    private String supplierCurrencyCode;

    private BigDecimal price; // In Supplier Currency;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    // where do I specify that the exchangeRate is joined using the 
    // supplierCurrencyCode property?
    private ExchangeRate exchangeRate

    public BigDecimal getPriceInLocalCurrrency() {
        BigDecimal rate = BigDecimal.valueOf(exchangeRate.rate);
        return price.multiply(rate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the foreign key columns name is `supplier_currency_code`

```
@Entity
public class Price {
    @Id
    private String priceId;

    // Must be read-only because this column is written by the ManyToOne mapping
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false) 
    private String supplierCurrencyCode;

    private BigDecimal price; // In Supplier Currency;

    @JoinColumn(name="supplier_currency_code")    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
    private ExchangeRate exchangeRate

    public BigDecimal getPriceInLocalCurrrency() {
        BigDecimal rate = BigDecimal.valueOf(exchangeRate.rate);
        return price.multiply(rate);
    }
}
```